# Как работают операции &~ в C

Tags: c, синтаксис

```
int y = 2, x = 3, z = 1, k;
k = y&~z;
```

Как здесь получается значение `2`? Как работают эти операции `&~`?

Comment: Зачем здесь `x`?

Answer (score 9):

Значение `y` равно `2`, что в двоичном представлении выражается набором битов `00..010`.

Значение `z` равно `1`, что в двоичном представлении выражается набором битов `00..001`.

Применение операции *инверсии битов* `~` к значению `z` дает набор битов `11..110`.

Затем операция *побитового-И* `&` применяется к двоичным представлениям `y` и `~z`, т.е. к `00..010` и `11..110` соответственно, что дает в результате двоичное представление `00..010`.

А это двоичное представление все того же `2`.

---

Отдельно стоит заметить, что побитовые манипуляции лучше производить с беззнаковыми типами, если нет специальной необходимости использовать знаковые типы.

Comment: spasibo ponial vso :)